# Defender not removes Gemius malware

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, malware

Sometimes my Chrome browser opens window with Gemius advertising:

`https://gasurvey.gemius.com/recruiting/index.php?lang=en&sid=61998`

[image]

I suppose Windows Defender should remove this virus. But why it doesn't? Why? What is the best way to remove this virus?

UPD 2

Tried to fix search engine, but could not find any records related to Gemius:

[image]

UPD

I was trying to uninstall Gemius from system and Chrome according to [manual](https://www.2-spyware.com/remove-gemius-virus.html), but found nothing with name `Babylon`.

Comment: Not a virus so no, Windows Defender shouldn't. Some anti-malware apps do detect and remove it. And you can simply uninstall it.

Comment: I was trying to uninstall Gemius from system and Chrome according to manual, but found nothing with name `Babylon`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the Gemius malware on the chrome. was it the same on the other browsers?

Try to reset the chrome's **Home and Search Pages**:

1. Open Chrome.
2. Click **Customize and control Google Chrome** in the right-top of the page and click **Setting**.
3. Find **On startup** ->delete the homepage link and click **OK**.
4. Or set it as **Open the New Tab page**
5. Click **Change** link of **Appearance** and delete the homepage link for Gemius and click **OK**.
6. Click **Manage search engines** and delete the url, then click **OK**.
7. Close and restart Chrome.

Or we can try reset the chrome or clean up the computer on the chrome.
[image]

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Tried to fix search engine, but could not find any records related to Gemius. More details in UPD in  question body.